# center a hover only image

Tags: css, image, hover

I'm using CSS to show an image when I hover over the links in my list item's. I'm having two problems

1. How can I ensure the hover images are centered on the page when they are shown
2. How can I hide the 'col-2" div in the middle of the page ONLY when the list 
   items links are hovered over.

If there is a simple way of doing this via vanilla js Dom scripting I'm open to it, but no jQuery. Many thanks!

CSS -

```
    /* absorbing paddings within the div's width, instead of adding it 
        on top */
        * { 
        box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        header {
         padding-top: 10px;
         }

 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}


#col-1 {
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}

#col-1, p h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

#col-1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.col-1, ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.projectList li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

#col-2 {
    width: 45%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    }

/* display image on hover */

a:hover:after {
    content: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg/870px-Arsenal_FC.svg.png); 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="globalName">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

        </div>
     </header>

      <div id="col-1">
       <div id="pageContent">
        <ul class="projectList">

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
     </div>



        <div id="col-2">
        <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the image as an `image-background` of the `:after` on the hovered link.

By the way, I think you can't select the **`#col-2`** on the `li:hover` only by css.

```css
/* absorbing paddings within the div's width, instead of adding it 
        on top */
* { 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

header {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}


#col-1 {
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}

#col-1, p h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

#col-1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.col-1, ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.projectList li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

#col-2 {
    width: 45%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    }

/* display image on hover */

a:hover:after {
    content: "";
    margin: 0;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg/870px-Arsenal_FC.svg.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="globalName">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

        </div>
     </header>

      <div id="col-1">
       <div id="pageContent">
        <ul class="projectList">

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
     </div>



        <div id="col-2">
        <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis. </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this displays the image nicely. However if I hover the bottom list item, the image is displayed lower, whereas if I hover the top list item the image is displayed higher on the page, if you get the drift...

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I didn't understand the first question correctly. I'll edit the post soon.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the after element which holds the image to absolute the center it. Check below if it helps

you can use background-image instead of content: like this

```
a:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    padding: 8%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg/870px-Arsenal_FC.svg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```css
/* absorbing paddings within the div's width, instead of adding it 
        on top */
        * { 
        box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        header {
         padding-top: 10px;
         }

 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}


#col-1 {
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}

#col-1, p h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

#col-1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.col-1, ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.projectList li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

#col-2 {
    width: 45%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    }

/* display image on hover */

/**
a:hover:after {
    content: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg/870px-Arsenal_FC.svg.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}**/

a:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%); */
    padding: 13%;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg/870px-Arsenal_FC.svg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="globalName">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

        </div>
     </header>

      <div id="col-1">
       <div id="pageContent">
        <ul class="projectList">

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Project<span><img src="" alt="" height="" /></span></a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
     </div>



        <div id="col-2">
        <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis.
```

Comment: this works, but the content of the second div is still behind the image. I'm thinking to use javascript to hide this div as well as display the image when I hover the li link.

Comment: Updated the code. to place the imgae at the back yo can use z-index for that..This should put you on a good path